# nginx progy pass doesn't work in Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have two web sites urls like example.com and wp-example.site.cloud. 
wp-example is Wordpress blog of example.com and I want to open it in example.com/blog so I did it in example.com nginx.

```
location ^~ /blog {

        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_request_buffering off; # Disable any internal request bufferring.
        proxy_pass http://wp.lunato;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
     #   proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

    }
```

It works fine but when I open Wordpress admin  the blog is removed from url and return 404 for me. 
*The main page of Wordpress is fine but when I open a page from menu there is no /blog in the url and returns 404*.
Any idea for this problem?

Comment: Can you share me live url?

Comment: sure 
lunato.net is the main site and lunato.net/blog is the blog which the main url of blog is wp-lunato.fandogh.cloud but i made it to lunato.net/blog with prox pass

Comment: Can you try https://lunato.net/blog/wp-admin/   With slash end of the url

Comment: it works but problem is when i go to admin panel and all links are without /blog like : lunato.net/wp-admin/edit.php

Comment: Can you check htaccess and go to databse check site url in option table

Comment: my site and home url are lunato.net/blog and what should i check in .httacces?

Comment: RewriteBase /blog/ it should be have in htaccess it also not working download sql file  find /wp-admin

Comment: let me check it out

Answer (score 0):

i solved it

wordpress change url automaticity with a js code so i add a js in wp-admin/admin-footer.php this code add /blog in url after wordpress remove it :D